# Location of AJAX in PHP MVC?

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller

Where should my called AJAX file be residing in a typical PHP MVC framework?

It's logic, so I'm assuming the models folder, but at the same time it's acting as part of the controller functions?

Thanks!

---

Thanks for all the responses, particularly zerkms.

JS will form part of the view, which will AJAX request a URL. The URL will be an independent controller (possibly an AJAX controller in itself) which will provide the JS with it's datasource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *presentational* logic, so it belongs to presentation, `View` part.

Whereas `Model` layer represents *business* logic.

Comment: It sounds like a controller to me, although the question is not very informative.

Comment: @Jon: it's definitely a `View`. If you left the current controllers and models and replace views with another ones (for example by moving from web to win32 application) would you still have ajax? (I assume that models and controllers are perfectly abstracted from a particular View implementation and such change is theoretically possible)

Comment: What about in the case where ajax calls merely return json (versus html)? Is this still a view? I've had a bit of confusion on this as well

Comment: Supporting zerkms here, definitely goes in the view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply zerkms . Problem is I can't start instantiating objects in the view, and any existing ones available to to parent view won't be available? What more info can I give so you can make a suggestion @Jon

Comment: @Kenny Cason: if you decide to change the presentation from ajaxy thing to plain web 1.0. Why would you want to modify anything but just view?

Comment: @Craig Wilson: your original question is pure theoretical one. Now you're talking about some practical limitations. That's confusing ;-)

Comment: @zerkms I didn't 100% follow your last statement. but as I was a bit confused I have always basically treated my app as having four components, model, view, controller, and rest. Most all of ajax handling is RESTful, and the times where I do need ajax to load html or such, I just load a view of course. Does that sound bizarre to you?

Comment: @Kenny Cason: In the MVC paradigm ajax client (js) belongs to view. Just because it's a part of presentation layer. That's it

Comment: Practically then, how would we work around making objects available to the requested AJAX file?

Comment: @Craig Wilson: Uhm, I've re-read the question and all the comments once again: are you asking about sever-side (php) or client-side (js) part of AJAX interaction?

Comment: In short, both. JS as part of a MVC based PHP application. The JS will be using the jQuery lib to communicate with the application. Thanks for your responses so far.

Comment: @Craig Wilson: well, then the `js` part of AJAX is a view, and server-side of AJAX is both Controller and Model

Comment: So, if the JS was part of the view, it will call a controller, which will in turn call the necessary model?

Comment: @Craig Wilson: JS calls some url. It doesn't call a controller. Treat url as some datasource. And from the opposite side - ajax controller is also a controller like any other.

Comment: But where should the "datasource" be located, I'm confused as to what type of file this should be? (Should I be instantiating objects again to call methods to get the data I need, in which case, it's acting as a controller?)

Comment: @Craig Wilson: "server-side of AJAX is both Controller and Model". Where your other controllers are located? Put the one that serves ajax request to the same place. AJAX request is nothing more than regular HTTP request and you shouldn't treat "regular" and "ajax controllers" as something different

Comment: It must be a controller, I can't see how it could be structured to be both? Are we then not in a situation where we are calling a controller (or both) from a view? (I must emphasize I'm not in any way criticizing, I very much appreciate your views on this!).

Comment: @Craig Wilson: "Are we then not in a situation where we are calling a controller (or both) from a view?" --- no. You call an url. And your controller processes some ordinary request from somewhere.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense. So would it be best practice to have a controller solely responsible for processing AJAX requests, with it's own objects independent from the (parent) view?

Comment: @Craig Wilson: yep, personally I follow something like that

Comment: @CraigWilson; the only thing the Controller does is direct the traffic; it doesn't matter if it's regular POST, GET, or AJAX. Since your AJAX is probably requesting data, you need Controller to direct the AJAX request to the proper Model class, retrieve the data, and pass it to a View class for display. So, in short, you still need the 3 components

Comment: @Sam , there is no such thing as "proper model class". Model is a layer. And correctly written controller **does not** retrieve data from model layer and it **does not** pass that data to view. Please stop spreading BS.

Comment: @tereško, I meant the appropriate Model class. Yes, I understand that Model is a layer; however, that layer comprises of classes, interfaces, and other objects, which is distinguishable from those of the Controller and the View.

Comment: @Sam , FYI , MVC pattern is made of two layers : presentation layer and model layer. There are no "presentation" classes. What you call "models" are actually [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject), and they should not be exposed to presentation layer.

Comment: @tereško, aka Model; the **M** component of the MVC pattern; otherwise, it's just **VC** or **CV**, which sounds very ridiculous.

Comment: What the hell are you talking about ?!? **Model is not a component!** It is a layer. Layer are conceptual groups of structures in OOP. The model layer in MVC consists of services, domain objects, repositories, data mappers, units of work, data access object and other structures. Model is NOT any single entity. Same way as presentation layer is not any single object, it in turn consists of views, controllers, templates and other structures. **If you learned MVC by reading tutorial for a framework, then just STOP!!**

Comment: @tereško, I didn't learn MVC from any framework (I don't use any); however, I already realize that you are a purist; thus, everyone must use the right words as you to describe similar concepts. I'm positively certain that we are referring to the same concept, especially given your last explanation. MVC comprises of logical layers, and each layer is composed of zero/multiple objects. Let's not waste time and space debating over name differences if the ideas are already in sync. it's unproductive.

Comment: @Sam , especially since the original point was about `correctly  written controller does not retrieve data from model layer and it does not pass that data to view. Please stop spreading BS.` Which was about pointing out that your interpretation of MVC pattern is completely wrong. Controller in MVC is supposed to change the state of model layer and current view. It is **NOT** for sassing around data of dealing with access control.

Comment: @tereško, do you have a book/link to prove that? Because I have some books and links that prove me right. According to my sources, Controller calls Model, Model performs logic and returns data; Controller passes this data to View. I have some sources that passes data from Model straight to View, but in those, the View is usually injected into the Model. I'll be happy to read about more accurate implementations, as long as they are from verifiable sources; just accepting your words isn't enough. (BTW,I used Controller, Model, and View to replace the actual objects in each layer).

Comment: @Sam , you could always just read the "Component interaction" segment in the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller). Of course that article is quite pitiful. If you really want to research the pattern you should start by reading [GUI Architectures](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) by *Martin Fowler* or the [PoEAA book](http://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Martin/dp/0321127420). Also reading the [original definition](http://www.itu.dk/courses/VOP/E2005/VOP2005E/8_mvc_krasner_and_pope.pdf) would be beneficial.

Comment: @Sam , what you are describing is either an extremely simplified version of [MVP design pattern](http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf), or the bastardization of MVC created by Rails (i kinda suspect that this is the case), where view has been turned in a dumb template and "models" are instances of ActiveRecord ORM.

Comment: I cannot comment beyond this point since I'm yet to read the links you have provided. So, maybe we'll meet again on another comment page. Thanks for the links.

Comment: Bringing this up again as i am in a similar situation. From what i understand, an option for handeling ajax requests is to have a controller that is dedicated for these requests, this controller will interact with the different models, and then the view. Wouldbmnt this be redundant and sort of lose the point of reusable code? Maybe i dont fully umderstand, but if i have an ajax controller, and a merhod in that controller that eventually renders a post list, and i have a regular cobtroller than renders a post list, wont they be very similar and use almost the same scripts?

Comment: They could both work with the same model, and just send the data to the view in a different way (one is by ajax and one is a regular view). But wouldnt it sort of lose the whole aspect of reusing code if the two different controllers are that similar?

Comment: @K.D you're reusing the model. Controllers are supposed to be skinny, so there was nothing to "reuse" really.

Comment: Then maybe the way i use controllers is a bit not efficient? The way is use controllers is by having them get the data from the model, which they pass to the view as "view_data" (which includes data for the sidebar also), and the controller also passes to the view another array called "view_settings". So my concern is that with my current set up, i would basically have the same controller, just it would have different view settings, and it would need less view data because its just loading a part of a page.  But besides those it would be the the same controller as the regular one.

Comment: @K.D it's okay for different controllers to fetch similar sets of data

Comment: Ok, would it make more sense to have the main method in the regular controller, say /posts/new, new as the method, detect if the request is with ajax, and if so then call an ajax method? Or would it be better to have all ajax requests in a single controller?

Comment: @K.D have them separate

Comment: Thanks for your answers, its really helping me understand this. I do still have concerns about this, for example, i have a form that can be submitted either with ajax or normal load, this loads a controller method, and that method handles the form, and performs different operations (split between different methods), if i had a separate controller for the ajax request of this form submission, wouldn't that mean that i would have to copy all of those functionalities and code from the "normal" controller to the ajax one? resulting in a lot of similar code, making things harder to maintain?

Comment: @K.D is this a real or imaginary problem? If real - please share your code and post it as a question.